# How to get Python functions to calculate maths operations?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this assignment to create a program that asks user to input any positive integer repeatedly or type anything else to end and generate the sum, count and average of the numbers.  My teacher wants all the code in these this structure with these three def’s only

This is the code I have, any suggestions on how to get it to work?

```
def calcAverage(total,count):
    sum = 0
    count = 0
    average = sum / count 

def inputNumber(message):
    while True:
        try:
            userInput = int(input(message))
            count = count + 1
            sum = sum + entry
                if userInput < 0:
                   raise ValueError
             except ValueError:
                main()
        else:
          return userInput 
          break

entry = inputNumber('Type any positive integer, anything else to quit')

def main():
    print('Sum')
    print(sum)
    print('Average')
    print(average)
    print('Total Numbers')
    print(count)
```

Comment: What's going wrong with what you have?

Comment: Hi Nicole, it seems like you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how functions work in python. None of your functions are returning values but you are trying to print variables defined inside of the functions. Perhaps you should dive a little deeper on functions [here](https://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/functions.html).

Comment: You have Indentation Error. [Edit] your Question and add the Errors you get.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not well explained + we don't really get what the boundaries are. Moreover, you should clearly state what is not working. Now, to give you some hint, this is how I would do it:

```
input = None
L = list()
while True:
    try:
        input = int(input('Type any positive integer, anything else to quit: '))
        if input < 0:
            break
        else:
            L.append(input)
    except:
        break

S = sum(L)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to use exceptions here. Condition statements would make it clearer.
I would put the valid inputs in a list until the user make a invalid input. When it happens, just get out of your while loop using a break statement and return the result.

Comment: The use of a try / except is quite useful to check if a user input is valid.